# What would cause an app to work when installed via USB, but not when installed from the Play store

Tags: android, titanium

I have a Titanium Android app that I'm developing and recently deployed to the Google Play store. The app works just fine when I install it directly on the device from the Titanium Studio workspace; however, when I try to install it from the Google Play store it does not work. The "does not work" feature in question here is a call to an https web service to authenticate a user. Also, I've noticed that ICS users are able to get the app to work from the Play store, whereas Gingerbread users are not if that's helpful.

This is the code that causes a problem:

```
var actInd=Titanium.UI.createActivityIndicator({height:80, width:200, message:'Logging In...', font:{fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue', fontSize:18,fontWeight:'bold'}, color:'white', style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.BIG});
actInd.show();
//Validating Data
var xhr2 = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr2.onload = function(){
    var response=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    if(response.resultinfo.result){
        ticket = response.resultinfo.ticket;
        Titanium.App.Properties.setString("uname",username.value);
        actInd.message='Successful...';
        actInd.show();
    }
};
xhr2.onerror = function(){
    Ti.API.info('in utf-8 error for GET');
};
xhr2.open("GET","https://example.com/login.cfm");
xhr2.send({"userid":username.value,"password":password.value});
```

In the problem case the app just hangs on showing the "Logging In..." message.

Comment: Anything useful in the adb log?

Comment: Well, when I use adb to load the app everything works fine. I'm not quite sure how to see logs for stuff that's running from the Play store. I don't see any crash reports in there.

Comment: Start up the app installed from Play, then run adb logcat. If you're only used to using adb from inside Eclipse, open up the DDMS perspective and highlight the running device (of course it has to be plugged in) in the Devices tab. The LogCat tab should start showing you output.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still pretty much a noob at all of this. The only interesting thing I saw was "HTTP Error (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException): No peer certificate." This seems odd to me though because I am able to make other https calls to the same server successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Hydrangea I was able to isolate the problem as a certificate validation error. Apparently there is an issue with some versions of Android prior to ICS not correctly validating valid SSL certificates even though they are setup properly. There is a setting in the [Titanium.Network.HTTPClient](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) called "validatesSecureCertificate" that defaults to false for testing, but to true when an app is released for distribution. This is why the problem was occurring only on the Play store version. Setting this to false seems to solve the problem and I believe it is safe to do so at a per-call level.

Comment: Hummm you have any idea if its a appcelerator's bug and if they will correct it soon?

Comment: They have it documented so I'm assuming they're not admitting it's a bug on their end.

Comment: Definitely not a bug. Funny that you ran into this months ago, here is a new blog post discussing this property: http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/11/the-titanium-sdk-and-certificate-validation.html

Comment: Yes, they should give me some sort of credit in their blog post too :)